# Query on dynamically refreshing a view in Backbonejs

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js

I am new to Backbonejs. I have to make changes to a piece of code in a relatively big project. It is difficult to explain the exact problem here, but I will try.

The folder structure for the app is http://grab.by/xC1q .  In this app I want to load new set of videos  after I perform certain actions without the page reload.

In Backbone.js you can bind views to models or collections and then any changes in the collections would automatically refresh the view. I have spent quite a lot of time, trying to get this right, but it doesn't work.

I am checking certain parameters against session variables, so reloading the page does work and it renders on the UI as desired.However, I want to do it without reloading the page, so I tried calling app.init() or loading main.js again, but somehow it went into infinite loop and then the screen got frozen. If this is a quick way of achieving, what I am trying to achieve, how can this be done?

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of re-running `app.init()` which will come with a lot of baggage, you should look at [Backbone.Collection.fetch()](http://backbonejs.org/#Model-fetch) and [Backbone.Model.fetch()](http://backbonejs.org/#Collection-fetch) to refresh your models or collections and refresh their associated views.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I tried to use it, but the code seems to0 complex for me to finish the changes in quick time. Is there a way using app.init()? That would help me a lot

Comment: There probably isn't. `app.init()` usually does a lot more than just refresh data (although it's up to each developer to define exactly what `app.init()` does so I won't know unless I see it)

Comment: After you fetch the new collection you can re-render the view to show the latest collection